# How to monkey patch the Ruby module

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching

I have this simple ruby module. I was able to monkey patch a Ruby class but this time I want to monkey patch a simple Ruby module, I tried using
this approach but it did not work. I thought that it will work because it works when I monkey patch a simple Ruby class.

```
Mymodule.class_eval do
 def self.function1
   "monkey patched function1 >>>"
 end
end
```

This is the original Mymodule that we want to monkey patch:

```
module Mymodule
  def self.function1
    'this is function1'
  end 
end
```

sample usage:

```
puts Mymodule.function1()
# -> output: this is function1
```

Any idea on how to monkey patch the module?

Comment: "it did not work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: I don't see any problem. When I copy&paste your code, I get the exact result I would expect, namely `"monkey patched function1 >>>"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply re-open the class and redefine `Mymodule.function1`.

```
module Mymodule
  def self.function1
    'monkey patched function1 >>>'
  end 
end
```

That being said, your proposed code worked fine too:

```
module Mymodule
  def self.function1
    'this is function1'
  end 
end

Mymodule.class_eval do
  def self.function1
    'monkey patched funtion1 >>>'
  end 
end


puts Mymodule.function1
# monkey patched funtion1 >>>
```